# How to find specific character/string at the end of each line of a file and add that character if missing except the last line?

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed

I have a file which should have specific character/string at the end of each line except the last line. How to achieve this by shell script that it searches that character/string at the end of each line and add that character/string if not present?

For example, the file contents like:

```
hello1
hello
hell1
hel
end
```

it should have the character 1 at the end of each line except the last line and the output of our script should be like:

```
hello1
hello1
hell1
hel1
end
```

I think it can be written using sed or awk but I am not sure how do they works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should the character be _removed_ from the last line if it found at the end of that line?

Answer (score 2):

One way can be

```
 sed -e '
    s/1$/&/;t
    $!s/$/1/
' file
```

```
sed -e '
  $q; /1$/!s/$/1/
' file
```

Or:

```
sed -e '$!{/1$/!s/$/1;}'
```

Or if there are no empty lines:

```
sed -e '$!s/[^1]$/&1/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```
sed '$!s/1\{0,1\}$/1/'
```

(some `sed` implementations support the non-standard `\?` as an alternative to `\{0,1\}`).

Or its extended regexp equivalent for those `sed` implementations that support `-E` (soon to be standard):

```
sed -E '$!s/1?$/1/'
```

That is, on all lines except (`!`) the last (`$`), replace one optional (`\{0,1\}`/`?`) trailing (`$`) `1` with `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{print p 1} {sub(/1$/,""); p=$0} END{print p}' file
hello1
hello1
hell1
hel1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can (in sed):

1. Remove all `1` where they exist.   `s/^\(.*\)1$/\1/`
2. Then add it back for all lines.    `s/.*/&1/`
3. But only for lines that are not the last one `$!{…}`

```
sed '$!{s/^\(.*\)1$/\1/;s/.*/&1/}' file
```

Or, without capturing anything (no asterisks), one of the two:

```
sed '$!{s/1$//;s/$/1/}' file
sed '/1$/b;$!s/$/1/' file
```

Comment: Dear @Isaac thanks for your prompt response. I am getting the following error:

sed: -e expression #1, char 16: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: Please try again, this website failed to preserve the code. Now correctly formatted.

Comment: Note that `sed '/1$/b;$!s/$/1/'` is GNU-specific. POSIXly: `sed -e '/1$/b' -e '$!s/$/1/'`. Actually, they're all GNU specific, as you also need `}` to be delimited from the previous commands (with `;` or newline or a separate `-e`) portably.